# Highcharts (9.0.1): drilldown problem after change chart type dynamically

Tags: highcharts

I'm an highcharts beginner...and this is my problem:
I have a 3 level drilldown chart with the possibility to change graph using buttons.
Start with a 'column' chart and drilldown to the first level; now if I change the chart type to 'pie' and try to drilldown, this last action does not work correctly
Can you help me?
Thks

```js
var  series = [{
  name: 'Nascite',
  id:   'Nascite',
  data: [{
    name:       '2018',
    y:          1000,
    drilldown:  'Nascite 2018'
  },{
    name:       '2019',
    y:          200,
    drilldown:  'Nascite 2019'
  }]
}];

var drilldown = {
  series: [{
    name: 'Nascite 2018',
    id:   'Nascite 2018',
    data: [{
      name:       'USA',
      y:          800,
      drilldown:  'Nascite 2018 USA'
    }, {
      name:       'ITALY',
      y:          900,
      drilldown:  'Nascite 2018 ITALY'
    }]
  }, {
    name: 'Nascite 2019',
    id:   'Nascite 2019',
    data: [{
      name:       'USA',
      y:          200,
      drilldown:  'Nascite 2019 USA'
    }]  
  },{
    name: 'Nascite 2018 USA',
    id:   'Nascite 2018 USA',
    data: [{
      name:       'Texas',
      y:          100
    },{
      name:       'California',
      y:          500
    }]
  },{
    name: 'Nascite 2018 ITALY',
    id:   'Nascite 2018 ITALY',
    data: [{
      name:       'TrentinoAA',
      y:          400,
      drilldown:  'Nascite 2018 ITALY TrentinoAA'
    }]
  },{
    name: 'Nascite 2019 USA',
    id:   'Nascite 2019 USA',
    data: [{
      name:       'Texas',
      y:          200
    }]
  },{
    name: 'Nascite 2018 ITALY TrentinoAA',
    id:   'Nascite 2018 ITALY TrentinoAA',
    data: [{
      name:       'Trento',
      y:          300
    },{
      name:       'Bolzano',
      y:          100
    }]
  }]
};

const chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
      type: 'column',
      events: {
        drillup:  function(e){},
        drilldown:  function(e){}
      }
    },
    drillInventory: [],
    title: {
        text: 'Chart.update'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Plain'
    },
    xAxis: {
      type: 'category'
    },
    yAxis: {},
    series: series,
    drilldown: drilldown
});

document.getElementById('plain').addEventListener('click', () => {
    chart.update({
      chart: {
        type: 'column'
      }
    });
});

document.getElementById('pie').addEventListener('click', () => {
    chart.update({
      chart: {
        type: 'pie'
      }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/data.js"></script>
<script src="https://github.highcharts.com/modules/drilldown.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

<button id="plain">Plain</button>
<button id="pie">Pie</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a bug - I reproted it on the Highcharts Github issue channel where you can follow this thread - https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/15496